# Segmentation fault con matriz asignada por strlen

Tags: c

Quiero crear el cifrado César, también conocido como cifrado por desplazamiento, `caesar.c` con C. Recibo el numero en la variable como un argumento `./caesar 2` por ejemplo. Lo utilizo en `key`. En una matriz de String `s` recibo el texto sin formato. En `encryptedASCII[strlen(s)]` voy a hacer las modificaciones.

**Sin embargo, recibo una `Segmentation fault`**. Pensaba que estaba porque el tamaño de la matriz fue asignada dinamicamente pero persiste la errora cuando hizo `encryptedASCII[1000]`

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    int key = atoi(argv[2]);

    if (key<0)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    printf("¿Que quiere cifrar?\n");
    string s = GetString();
    int encryptedASCII[strlen(s)];
    char encryptedText[strlen(s)];

    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(s); i < n; i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(s[i]))
        {
        encryptedASCII[i] = ('s[i]' +key)%26;
        encryptedText[i]=encryptedASCII[i];
        }    
    }


    //Aqui estamos fijando el texto cifrado 
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(s); i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", encryptedText[i]);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `encryptedASCII[i] = ('s[i]' +key)%26;` ¿Esa línea te compila? Todo apunta a que esas comillas simples sobran...

Comment: @eferion Es necesarion porque permiter obtener el codigo ASCII de la letra que debemos cifrar: https://youtu.be/V6IDxl-3WAA?t=6m3s

Comment: No perdona, ahí el programa intentará interpretar `'s[i]'` con un caracter en el sentido literal en vez de pretende leer el caracter almacenado en  `s[i]`. Si lo cambias por comillas dobles lo verás más claro `"s[i]"` es una cadena de caracteres mientras que `s[i]` recupera el carácter almacenado en la posición `i` el buffer `s`

Comment: @eferion Entiendolo. Sin embargo, trad modificar el programo por `encryptedASCII[i] = (s[i] +key)%26` persiste el error de segmetnation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu programa tiene varios problemas:

```
encryptedASCII[i] = ('s[i]' +key)%26;
```

En esa línea sobran las comillas simples. En C las comillas simples se emplean para declarar caracteres. Tu estás intentando acceder al carácter ubicado en la posición `i` del buffer `s` luego lo correcto sería poner:

```
encryptedASCII[i] = (s[i] +key)%26;
```

Otro problema en esta línea es ese `%26`. Si haces `Z = X mod Y` vas a obtener en `Z` un número en el rango (0..Y-1). Si hechas un vistazo a la tabla ASCII verás que los primeros caracteres se corresponden con símbolos no imprimibles. Dicho en cristiano: estás generando basura. Lo que tu pretendes poner es:

```
encryptedASCII[i] = (((s[i] - 'A') + key)%26) + 'A';
```

Es decir, primero pasas el juego de caracteres, que estará en el rango (A..Z), es decir (65..90) al rango (0..26), después realizas el desplazamiento y calculas el módulo. Tras estos pasos obtienes un número en el rango (0..26) y sólamente te falta volver a mover el rango para obtener un carácter.

Un tercer error importante lo tienes en:

```
if (isalpha(s[i]))
{
  encryptedASCII[i] = (s[i] +key)%26;
  encryptedText[i]=encryptedASCII[i];
}
```

¿Qué sentido tiene ahí `encryptedASCII`? Si es un mero intermediario podrías usar una variable tipo `int` a secas.

¿Qué sucede si `s[i]` no es una letra? Básicamente que en `encryptedText[i]` vas a dejar la basura que hubiese porque no has inicializado el buffer.

¿Qué sucede si `s[i]` contiene un carácter en minúsculas? Que el resultado va a ser una variable aleatoria porque el rango (a..z) no es el mismo que (A..Z)

Como nota final comentarte que el tipo `string` que usas es un burdo alias de `char*` y la función `GetString()` te está devolviendo un puntero. ¿Seguro que no hay que borrar ese puntero para evitar fugas de memoria?

¿Por qué usas `GetString()` en vez de hacer la lectura a mano? Son dos líneas, no te vas a matar a escribir:

```
char s[200];
scanf("%s",s);
```

Ya te aviso que esa librería `cs50.h` no es para nada estándar y no vas a aprender absolutamente nada usándola.

Y bueno, a modo de corolario, no estaría de más asegurarse de que `argv[2]` es válido.

Cuando tu pasas argumentos a un programa por línea de comandos éstos se almacenan en `argv`. ¿Cuántos argumentos hay? Eso es algo que te dice `argc`.

Y eso sí, los argumentos se encontrarán en:

- `argv[0]` -> Nombre del ejecutable
- `argv[1]` -> Primer parámetro
- `argv[2]` -> Segundo parámetro
- ...

¿Estás seguro de que `argv[2]` no es realmente `argv[1]`?

Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias! En efecto, fue `argv[1]`. Sin embargo el texto tiene un error importante porque tengo ahora:

`c⎺┌⎺c▒┼├⎺☃┼e@☃de5▮:·/┬⎺⎼┐⎽⎻▒ce/⎻⎽e├2 $ ↓/c▒e⎽▒⎼ 2                                                                                                                                                                                                    
W▒▒├ ☃⎽ ├▒e ├e│├ ├⎺ be e┼c⎼≤⎻├ed?
He┌┌⎺!
JMTTWc⎺┌⎺c▒┼├⎺☃┼e@☃de5▮:·/┬⎺⎼┐⎽⎻▒ce/⎻⎽e├2 $ ` y no `colocantoine@ide50:~/workspace/pset2 $ ./caesar 2
What is the text to be encrypted?
Hello`

Comment: Caracteres no imprimibles... ¿seguro que has leido toda la respuesta?

Comment: Fue impossible enteder esta errora, he recargado la pagina. En efecto utilizo  esa librería `cs50.h`, pero me da tambien `isupper`, `islower` porque no se como hacerlos por lo momento. ¿Como hacerlos por mi propio?

Comment: Mira la librería `ctype.h` tiene `int isupper(int c);` y  `int islower(int c);` Aunque por otro lado podrías hacer: `int isupper(char c){ return c>='A' && c <='Z'; }` y algo similar para `islower`. Un saludo